# Calling a function inside a variable (randomly)

Tags: python, function, variables

So, I have a collection of different questions, which are each asked depending on what function is called. I want to have it so for every question, a random type of question (function) is called. I think this is the best way to do it but I don't know why it's not working.

```
x = addition_question(int(random.randrange(0,101,1)),int(random.randrange(0,101,1)))

y = multiply_question(int(random.randint(1,10)),int(random.randint(1,10)))

z = subtract_question(int(random.randrange(0,101,1)),int(random.randrange(0,101,1)))

vars = [x,y,z]


import random

print("Question 1:")
print(random.sample(vars,1))
time.sleep(.25)
```

Running this returns this:
http://puu.sh/bP9dL/416caa5bc1.png

Instead of going to the line with 'print ("Question 1:")' it for some reason prints the functions without the variable being called.

NOTE: The error is in the randomising of the variables, and calling them. When I specify the type of question (function) I would like to use, it works as planned.

```
print("Question 1:")
addition_question(int(random.randrange(0,101,1)),int(random.randrange(0,101,1))) #creates addition question with randomised numbers between 1 and 101
print("")
time.sleep(.25)

print("Question 2:")
multiply_question(int(random.randint(1,10)),int(random.randint(1,10))) #creates multiplication question with randomised numbers between 1 and 10
print("")
time.sleep(.25)
```

Feel free to ask questions about the rest of the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already called your functions before storing them into the `vars` list. Just store references to the functions, and pass in random values for the arguments *after* picking one:

```
questions = (addition_question, multiply_question, subtract_question)
print("Question 1:")
random.choice(questions)(random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10))
```

The `random.choice()` picks one of the three function references at random, and the `(...)` part after the `random.choice()` call then *calls* that random function. At that moment we pass in randomly picked arguments.

Note that I did not use `int()` on the return value of `random.randint()`; that function already returns an integer and there is no need to turn that into an integer again. I also used `random.choice()` rather than use `random.sample()` with sample size of 1.

If your functions need different random integer ranges, then you have a few different options:

- store the ranges with the functions, say in a tuple, and after picking a tuple at random call `random.randint()` and the picked function:

  ```
  questions = (
      (addition_question, 0, 100),
      (multiply_question, 1, 10),
      (subtract_question, 0, 100),
  )

  question, low, high = random.choice(questions)
  question(random.randint(low, high), random.randint(low, high))
  ```
- Store lambdas; these are anonymous functions, *encapsulating* another expression to be executed when called:

  ```
  questions = (
      lambda: addition_question(random.randrange(101), random.randrange(101)),
      lambda: multiply_question(random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)),
      lambda: subtract_question(random.randrange(101), random.randrange(101)),
  )

  random.choice(questions)()
  ```

In the first option I adjusted the values to be usable for `random.randint()` and in the second I used the simplest form of `random.randrange()`; with just one argument it'll default the start to `0` and the step to `1`.

Comment: His code uses different random ranges for different questions, so simplifying it like this will break his logic. (His addition and subtraction questions take values from 0-100, while multiplication takes values from 1-10, which is pretty reasonable for drilling an elementary school student or similar.)

Comment: @abarnert: ah, I indeed missed that.

Comment: I guess the only problem with this that I cannot now have questions that use subtraction or addition which have numbers which are over 10. This is a great help though!

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused: abarnert pointed that out, I added some more options.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This still isn't the right numbers—he's using `randrange` for addition and subtraction, `randint` for multiplication, but you're using `randint` (with the same arguments) for all three.

Answer (score 0):

When you write lines like this:

```
x = addition_question(int(random.randrange(0,101,1)),int(random.randrange(0,101,1)))
```

That calls the function `addition_question` right now, and assigns the result of calling that function to `x`.

What you want to do is create something that you can lazily call later—and call repeatedly, getting a different value back each time.

The way do to that is to define a function:

```
def x():
    return addition_question(int(random.randrange(0,101,1)),int(random.randrange(0,101,1)))
```

And then, of course, you don't want to just print out `x`, you want to *call* `x` and print out the *result*:

```
print(random.sample(vars,1)())
```

That's all it takes.

---

A few side notes on your code:

- `random.randrange` returns an integer; there's no reason to pass its result to `int`.
- `random.sample(spam, n)` chooses `n` values without replacement; when `n` is always going to be `1`, `random.choice(spam)` does the same thing more simply and readably.
- `random.randrange`, like `range`, has default values for its parameters, so you can just write `randrange(101)`, not `randrange(0, 101, 1)`.
- Long lines of code with no spaces are hard to read, even more so in places like StackOverflow or a typical terminal window that can only fit 80 characters. Put spaces between arguments, break lines in two (or reorganize them into separate lines with intermediate values stored in temporary variables) if they get too long, etc. See [PEP 8(http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the standard Python style guide.

Comment: Thanks for the tips anyway...It's just a habit of mine to define everything i want to be an integer, as an integer.

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused: I don't think you're thinking about this properly. `int(3)` doesn't define anything as an integer in the way that, say, `int x = 3` would in C, it takes an integer and calls the convert-to-integer function on it at runtime.

Comment: @abarnert It's just from user inputs, where it automatically defines it as a string, rather than an integer.

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused: The important thing is to understand the type of what you have. `input` returns a string; `randint` and `randrange` return integers. Randomly throwing in conversions everywhere just makes your code harder to read, and it means when you inevitably miss one you have a harder time debugging why `0` and `"0"` aren't equal.

Comment: @abernert I understand this, I was trying to give you an explanation to why I might have done it ._.

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused: OK, I get it. Never mind then. :)